# Shader error while building for Android in URP

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

/* SOLVED */I've been trying to develop a mobile game in Unity 2022.3.0f1 LTS for a couple of days. When I try to build my game, Unity comes up with some errors, including shader ones. I looked it up but couldn't find any solutions and I'm new, so I'm kind of lost.

Here are the errors I received:
[image]

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Player settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.3/Documentation/Manual/android-build-settings.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.3/Documentation/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html

It is solved when I apply the settings exactly as what the pictures show on these webpages.

Comment: The link is helpful, but do consider putting in more detail into the answer.